# Is it possible to set an image background on the visual studio 2010 editor?

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I would really like to be able to put an image background on the editor window in vs2010, not just a color. Does anyone know if this is possible?

Answer (score 0):

This is all I've been able to find. It requires CodeRush, and I can't tell whether it has been updated to work with VS2010.

http://vsbackgroundchanger.codeplex.com/